# OAuth used for registration

Tags: oauth2

When I read and watch videos on Oath it talks more about being able to access data from other applications. However, a common usage of what I think is OAuth is simply identifying a user without requiring them to have a id/pw for a site. I don't see that explained very often though. What is the concept behind that process?

Say there is a forum website that lets you sign in via your google account. All it gets is your first and last name and you never have to create a pw for that site specifically because they go through the google OAuth process to ID you. How does that process work? Is that site storing some token on their db? Is that token specific to the user and your site and never changes so that each time they login via google to your site you can just validate the stored token in your sites DB vs the one google gave them?

Comment: `I don't see that explained very often though. What is the concept behind that process?` Ask for a ID token to the 3rd party service, so that your application can assert that you are who you are saying to be, just by sending the same ID Token to the 3rd party service an ask for confirmation.

Comment: You are missing one of the first steps of OAuth2, the 3rd party service ask you for a user and password. Don't they? That's your **authentication**. Your server will validate the ID Token and will gather all the info it needs from the 3rd party service for **authorize** to you to pass. That's your **authorization**. That's why OAuth is all about **authorization** and **not about authentication**

Comment: @Laiv What does it mean to "validate" the ID token? I mean my site is just getting back a token right? That token could come from anywhere. What constitutes validating the token? Is that token always the same for that person and my web app so that I can say this is x person in my database because I would have gotten the token on registration for this use and I stored it along with their name in my users table?

Comment: *`I mean my site is just getting back a token right?`* Right, the one the 3rd party gave to your client. *`What constitutes validating the token?`* send it back to the 3rd party service (who generate it) from your site (usually the server-side). *`Is that token always the same for that person`* They also expire. Some OAuth servers also give you back a *refresh token*. *`I would have gotten the token on registration for this use and I stored it along with their name in my user's table?`* You could, that's fairly common.

Comment: @Laiv "You could, that's fairly common" That's the part I'm referring to where I don't find many details about that usage. It's all about getting information from said app to use in another app, which this isn't really part of that exactly. It's really just being used so a site doesn't need to store and manage user passwords, which is the part I'm mostly interested in but have trouble finding that usage.

Comment: @Laiv "send it back to the 3rd party service (who generate it) from your site (usually the server-side)" Why would I do that when I'm trying to use it to validate that user on my site though? Couldn't the response be spoofed to say it's valid? I get if I WANTED something from said API that they wouldn't give me that sensitive info without a valid token but I don't care about any info they have when all I want to do is use it as a way to validate they are a valid use on my site.

Comment: Because it depends on the requirements. Maybe you onyl use the token once during the registration, bulk the data and trash the token. Or you keep It for later synchros with the 3th party service. Whether you store It and keeo it alive or not, is puere business. Depends on you.

Comment: @Laiv I'm so confused and not explaining or understanding fully :). There are sites where I can login with my google account. I never create a password for that site anywhere, yet the next time I log into the site via my google account they know me. How is that done? What steps happened to make that happen? What data was received and what data was stored on that sites DB?

Comment: You have sutumbled with one of the conocerns related to social logins. Usually the email, but email might change in some 3th party applications what would cause your application to generate a new account.

Comment: @Laiv That makes sense that it could cause an issue. If I logged onto a site with my facebook login and it used my email that facebook has to create my local account to that website, but then in a month change my email on my facebook account, and go back to the website to login it would think I'm a different person. I've seen it where the site asks for an ID but never asks for a password. I can only assume the access token is stored in the websites DB and checked after it got it from social login. But you said that can change which wouldn't work then.

Comment: Some applications (Google for example) gives you an array of emails :-). Facebook also has its own email that you barely use and It's unlikely to change

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is mainly about authorization delegation. i.e. you as a user, delegate the privileges to perform some operations on a resource that is owned by you, on behalf of you.

For instance, consider the use case, where you as the owner of the bank account (resource owner) have a financial consultant (Client) to manage your bank account (Bank being the resource server). There are 4 things in here:

1. Bank (Resource Server) and the financial consultant should have a trust  relationship whereby financial consultant has a specific clientID and secret with privileges scoped to perform certain activities on behalf of a user.
2. When the financial consultant (client) tries to perform a specific operation on behalf of you, the resource server or a authorization server that the bank relies on will throw a login screen to you. Once you login, it should ask for your consent to allow the financial consultant to perform the operation for you.
3. Based on your consent, the financial consultant is issued a token. In general it is a short lived to token (valid for 15 min - 1 hour) depending on the use case. The token will contain enough information indicating that the operation can be done **only** on your account.
4. Now the Financial consultant can use this token to perform those authorized operations on your bank account, on your behalf without concerning you with the need to authorize each individual action.